# How to embed a Collection of forms without javascript

Tags: php, symfony

Is it possible to embed a collection of forms **five times** without using javascript and display them in **form.twig** ?

**ProductType**

```
class ProductType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => true))
        ->add('description', 'text',  array('required' => true))
        ->add('price', 'text', array('required' => true))                        
        //embed this formType
        ->add('image', 'collection', array('type' => new ImageType())

        )
    ;
}
```

Form to be embed **ImageType**

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', 'texet', array('required' => true))
        ->add('file', 'file',  array('required' => true))
    ;

}
```

This is **Form.twig**

```
<form method="post" action="" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>

            {{ form_widget(form.name) }}

            {{ form_widget(form.description) }}

            {{ form_widget(form.price) }}

        <div>
            {{ form_widget(form.image) }}
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try populating your product entity with five image entities. Create new (not persisted) instances if you need.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to allow the user to add up to five images?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this is the best way or not but you can do it if you want exact 5 images to upload. And also you need to save your images manually.

comment bellow line:

```
 ->add('image', 'collection', array('type' => new ImageType())
```

In your Image Type :

```
class ImageType extends AbstractType
{ 
    private static $count = 0;
    private $index;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->index = self::$count++;
    }
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {  
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'texet', array('required' => true))
            ->add('file', 'file',  array('required' => true)); 
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'yourbundle_images_'.$this->index;
    }
```

In your controller write like this:

```
 for($i=1;$i<=5; $i++)
 {
      $image = new \YourBundle\Entity\Image();
      $img   = $this->createForm(new \YourBundle\Entity\ImageType(), $image);
      $images[$i] = $img->createView();
 }
```

render twig with $images array.

In you twig write code as below:

```
{% for i in 1..5 %}
    {{ form_widget(images[i].name) }}
    {{ form_widget(images[i].file) }}
{% endfor %}
```

This is stranger but you have to save your files/images like :

```
    for($i=1 ; $i<=5; $i++)
    {
        $img = new \YourBundle\Entity\Image();                    
        $filename = $request->get('acme_productbundle_image_'.$i); // Your generated field id will be here

        $file = $request->files->get('acme_productbundle_image_'.$i);

        $img->setName($filename['name']);
        $img->setFile($file['file']);
        $img->setProduct($product); // your related product 
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($img);
    }
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
```

One question i have why you don't want to use javascript. This is the best option. See here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html#allowing-new-tags-with-the-prototype

I Also wander for better answer from other. :)